# How do I find the soonest Java Date past midnight?

Tags: java, date, calendar

Let's say I have a date object marked for February 13th, 2013 at 11pm. I am trying to get the next soonest date object at say, 3am. So in this case, it will be February 14th, 2013 3am.

I could do this simply by adding 1 day to the date field and setting the time to 3:00am, but what about the following case:

I have a date object marked for February 14th, 2013 at 1am. Here, I would not need to add a day, but rather simply set the time.

Is there an elegant way to do this? Below is what i've done so far, which I think will work, but I was just wondering if there is an api out there that makes this easier. Something like getNextSoonestDate() or something

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

//myDate is some arbitrary date, like one of the examples posted above (i.e. feb 13th 11pm)
calendar.setTime(myDate);

//set the calender to be 3am
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);

//check if this comes before my current date, if so we know we need to add a day
if (calendar.getTime().before(myDate)){
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}
```

Comment: your code would not work at 02:00h

Comment: sure it would, 3am would not be before 2am, so we'd leave the day of year untouched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a pre-written method to do what you want to do, but writing a utility method is simple enough.

With that said, your code is close but will not work properly if `myDate` is between `3:00:00.001` and `3:59:59.999` (I assume you'd want it to return the occurrence on the next day in this case) -- you need to zero out the less significant fields:

```
public static Date getNextTime(Date base, int hourOfDay) {
    Calendar then = Calendar.getInstance();
    then.setTime(base);
    then.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    then.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    then.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    then.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    if (then.getTime().before(base)) {
        then.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }
    return then.getTime();
}

Date nextOccurrenceOf3am = getNextTime(myDate, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check hour of the day of the current date(passed date) and find out if it is greater than or equals to 3, if yes take next date. Otherwise today ..will not that do? It may not give the result when you want same date exactly at 3:00:00.